# How to print formatted Decimal value in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How to print formatted `Decimal` value in Swift? `NumberFormatter` works only with `NSNumber`, but `Decimal` is a struct. `String(format:)` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Decimal` is bridged with `NSDecimalNumber`, which is a subclass of `NSNumber` so `NSNumberFormatter` can handle it

```
let decimal = Decimal(11.24)
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
let string = formatter.string(from: decimal as NSDecimalNumber)!
```